# read_csv using Dask Dataframe - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to read multiple csv files using Dask:

```
df = dd.read_csv(path + '*.csv', usecols = relevant_columns)

df = df.compute()
```

and I encounter the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 73732: invalid start byte
```

I've tried multiple `encoding` types.

Comment: You could use `chardectect` to help guess as mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding

Comment: I've tried - sometimes it's ascii, sometimes utf-8 (it's about multiple files). I tried both and it didn't work.

Comment: If each file has a different encoding and nobody knows which is which - that's going to be a hard one to fix. Its possible that everything is in the same Windows single byte code page and most of them work because they don't happen to have any non-ascii characters in them. Ascii, utf-8 and code page all look the same for the first 127 characters. If its a windows code page, things are difficult because that same 0x93 is valid in many code pages and there is no way to automatically know that.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore rows with errors?

Comment: Yes. You could preprocess the files by opening in binary mode, reading line by line and doing `line.decode()` then write to a new file. Use a try/except inside the loop to drop bad lines. Another option is to `line.decode(errors="replace") to put a � in the bad position.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do that without reading and rewriting the files?

Comment: The `csv` module reads line by line. You could read into a python list and then make your dataframe. If dask uses the same options as pandas, you could add `encoding_errors='replace'` (or 'ignore') to the read_csv call.